# Why single byte is returned for single char when string is converted

Tags: java

As far as I know char in java is built from 2 bytes, so why this test passes?

```
assertEquals(4, "test".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).length);
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078314/isnt-the-size-of-character-in-java-2-bytes

Comment: Because you ask for bytes in UTF-8 encoding, not for Java's `Char`s?

Comment: You explicitly converted to UTF-8 encoding, so this is really not surprising.

Comment: Here's some reading https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UTF-8, the char's in the range 0x00 to 0x7F are only 1 byte.  Thus, it's 4 bytes long.

`"test".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16")`

..would return 8 bytes.

EDIT: Added @Rossums comment for more detail.

Comment: In UTF-8 chars in the range 0x00 to 0x7F are a single byte.  Beyond that they are two or more bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the extra detail.