# Is there a difference in SIZE between String "a" and a Char 'a'?

Tags: java, string, char, memory-optimization

Is there a difference in size between a String "a" and a Char 'a'?
Should you use a Char when you need to save single letters or numbers?

Comment: those are totally dif. objects that coincidentally print the same value...

Comment: So when should I use them and whats the main difference between them?

Comment: primitive `char` (or `Char` if you want object) ensures that the value is single character only.

Comment: maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078314/isnt-the-size-of-character-in-java-2-bytes or at least it may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note there are actually 3 cases

String "a"
Character 'a'
char 'a'

of these, char 'a' will take up the least amount of space (2 bytes), whereas Char 'a' and String "a" are both objects and so because of the memory overhead associated with an Object, both will be approximately the same size

Answer (score 1):

Let's get something vaguely scientific going on here. I created the following program which creates an array of 100 million characters or strings:

```
public class NewClass {
    private static final int SIZE = 100000000;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        char[] a = new char[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            a[i] = 'a';
        }
    }
}
```

I profiled it once using `char[]`, once using `String[]`, and once using `Character[]`.

The amount of used heap space:

```
char[]      : 267 million bytes
String[]    : 442 million bytes
Character[] : 437 million bytes
```

So `char` is roughly 60% of the size of a 1 character `String`, which is comparable in size to a `Character` (on my JVM).

Answer (score 0):

There is no size difference between a `String` of one letter and a `char` of one letter (referring to the backing `char` array of the `String`, that is).  Currently, they both require 2 bytes as per UTF-16 encoding, but non UTF-16 characters will only require 1 byte once Java 9 is released in July.

The `String` will obviously use up more memory than the primitive, but it sounds like you're prematurely optimizing.