# What is the Java equivalent of MB_LEN_MAX?

Tags: java, c, character-encoding, character, limit

In C's `<limits.h>` or C++'s `<climits>` is defined a macro constant `MB_LEN_MAX` which is described as being:

> maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character

The way I understand this is, is that it represents either the maximum size of a character (2 bytes in Java) or perhaps the biggest character literal you can make, eg. `'\n'` being 2 bytes and `'\uFFFF'` being 6 bytes.

Does anybody know what the "maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character" is in Java and if it is defined somewhere in the language specification?

Comment: If you don't know what it is (and that isn't obvious to me), what use would an equivalent be? / `char` is always the equivalent of two bytes though you shouldn't have to deal with that other than that they are in the range 0..65535, but code points can be larger.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but some info about characters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078314/isnt-the-size-of-character-in-java-2-bytes)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Porting C code to Java and require that I have an equivalent of the `limits.h` file defined.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Quite frankly I don't know if I'm after just the 2 bytes or the larger code points. :/

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you. One of the answers suggests it _might be_ a 4 byte maximum but I must search some more...

Comment: @FinnRayment It's probably worth looking at how it is actually used in the code that you are porting.